# Flask Opencv Recode mini Video clips

Tags: python, opencv

I am struggle with generate a mini video clips(Each are 10s video clips) when recording my webcam using open cv and python.

Basically I want to do cut the webcam video into 10S duration clips and store in a folder.
When I doing this video clips cut but when I checked first video clip has 100% of full video.
Second has about 75% of full video and third has about 50% and etc.

So how I can solve this.
I will put my hole code in below. Hope your help to fix that one

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
global rec, img, out
rec = 0

def gen_frames():
    global img
    while True:
        success, img = camera.read()

def record(out):
    global rec, img

    while(rec != False):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        out.write(img)

@app.route('/requests',methods=['POST','GET'])
def tasks():

    if request.form.get('rec') == 'Start/Stop Recording':
        global rec, img, out
        rec= not rec

        ############### This Part work when manualy recode on and off ###############

        # if rec:
        #     print("start")
        #     global out
        #     now=datetime.datetime.now()
        #     fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        #     p = os.path.sep.join(['clips', "vid_{}.avi".format(str(now).replace(":",''))])
        #     out = cv2.VideoWriter(p, fourcc, 25.0, size)
        #     thread = Thread(target = record, args=[out,])
        #     thread.start()

        # if(rec==False):
        #     print("stop")
        #     out.release()

        class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
            def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.event = threading.Event()

            def run(self):
                while (rec != False) and not self.event.is_set():
                    now=datetime.datetime.now()
                    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
                    p = os.path.sep.join(['clips', "vid_{}.avi".format(str(now).replace(":",''))])
                    out = cv2.VideoWriter(p, fourcc, 25.0, size)
                    
                    thread = Thread(target = record, args=[out,])
                    thread.start()
                    self.event.wait(10)

            def stop(self):
                self.event.set()

        tmr = TimerClass()

        if(rec):
            print("start")
            tmr.start()

        if(rec==False):
            print("stop")
            tmr.stop()

    elif request.method=='GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

Comment: I find this a bit much code. can this be simplified further? flask is probably not needed to reproduce the issue. strip out *everything* that isn't *vital* to causing the issue. the more stuff there is, the less likely it is that anyone will look at it.

Comment: it is long code which we may have problem to run - first you should use `print()` or `log` to see all values in all variables. Maybe you change some value and you don't reset it later.

Comment: all variables create outside function are global and you don't need uses `global` outside functions. You need `global` only inside functions to inform function that it has to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

Comment: instead of `os.mkdir` with `try/except` you can use `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)`

Comment: there is good rule: all `global` at the beginning of function. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: instead of `str(now).replace(":",'')` you can do like `now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M.%s")` or even directly `now.strftime("vid_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M.%s.avi")`

Comment: yea thank you all but my main problem is save video clips can any one help for that

Comment: I think your problem is that you create so many threads. In `TimerClass` you run loop which every 10 seconds create another thread to run `record` but you never stop previous thread with `record`. I think if you would use `print()` to see which part of code is executed then you will see it.

Comment: BTW: here is place for comments which don't have to be related with your main problem.

Comment: Thank you very  much @furas I will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me problem is that in loop in `TimerClass` you create new thread every 10 seconds but you never stop previous thread and it still records frames. I would write frames directly in `TimerClass` instead of using another thread.

OR thread `record()` should check time and stop after 10 seconds.

I use `timedelta` to calculate when to stop recording one file and to create next one. And I do it in `TimerClass` but you could do something similar in `record()`

`VideoWriter(..., 25.0)` doesn't write with `25fps` but it is only information for video players how fast to display this video. To get 10 seconds video you need sleep `0.04` because `1s / 25fps = 0.04` or you would have to write 250 frames (10s * 25fps = 250fps).

Because code needs also some time to work I would have to use `0.03` instead of `0.04` to get 10 seconds video.

---

Full working code.

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` to have all in one file - and everyone can simply copy and test it.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template, render_template_string
import cv2
import os
import datetime, time
import threading

# global varaibles

capture = False
rec = False
out = None
img = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 300

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

frame_width = int(camera.get(3))
frame_height = int(camera.get(4))
size = (frame_width, frame_height)

os.makedirs('./shots', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('./clips', exist_ok=True)

def gen_frames():
    global capture
    global img
    
    print('[DEBUG] gen_frames: start')

    while True:
        success, img = camera.read()
        
        if not success:
            break
        
        if capture:
            capture = False

            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            filename = "shot_{}.png".format(str(now).replace(":",''))
            path = os.path.sep.join(['shots', filename])

            print('[DEBUG] capture:', path)

            cv2.imwrite(path, img)

        frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
        
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    #return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template_string('''
Go to <a href="/requests">FORM</a>
''')

# define class only once
class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        seconds_10 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
        
        while rec and not self.event.is_set():
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            filename = "vid_{}.avi".format(str(now).replace(":", ''))
            path = os.path.sep.join(['clips', filename])
            
            fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
            out = cv2.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, 25.0, size)

            end = now + seconds_10
            
            print('[DEBUG] end:', end)
            
            while now < end and rec and not self.event.is_set():
                if img is not None:  # `img` can be `numpy.array` so it can't check `if img:`
                    out.write(img)
                time.sleep(0.03)  # 1s / 25fps = 0.04  # it needs some time for code.
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
        
            out.release()
            
    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

@app.route('/requests', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def tasks():
    global capture
    global rec
    
    print('[DEBUG] click:', request.form.get('click'))
    print('[DEBUG] rec  :', request.form.get('rec'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('click') == 'Capture':
            capture = True

        if request.form.get('rec') == 'Start/Stop Recording':
            rec = not rec
    
            tmr = TimerClass()
    
            if rec:
                print("start")
                tmr.start()
            else:
                print("stop")
                tmr.stop()
    
    #return render_template_string('index.html')
    return render_template_string('''
<img src="/video_feed"><br/>
<form method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="click" value="Capture">Capture</button>
<button type="submit" name="rec" value="Start/Stop Recording">Start/Stop Recording</button>
</form>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_cam = threading.Thread(target=gen_frames)
    thread_cam.start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with thread `record()`

```
def record(seconds):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    filename = "vid_{}.avi".format(str(now).replace(":", ''))
    path = os.path.sep.join(['clips', filename])
    
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(path, fourcc, 25.0, size)

    end = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    
    print('[DEBUG] end:', end)
    
    while now < end and rec:
        if img is not None:  # `img` can be `numpy.array` so it can't check `if img:`
            out.write(img)
        time.sleep(0.03)  # 1s / 25fps = 0.04  # it needs some time for code.
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

    out.release()

# define class only once
class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        length = 10
        while rec and not self.event.is_set():
            t = threading.Thread(target=record, args=(length,))
            t.start()
            self.event.wait(length)
            
    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()
```